# Is there a way to reverse the bit order in UInt64?

Tags: swift, binary, uint64, bitboard

I am building a chess engine in Swift based off a tutorial written in Java. In the tutorial, Java's signed 64 bit integer `long` has a static method called `reverse(long i)` that "Returns the value obtained by reversing the order of the bits in the two's complement binary representation of the specified long value." It basically reverses the order of the binary bits so that, using 8-bit for simplicity's sake, `01000000` would become `00000010`.

I am curious if there is a way to accomplish the same thing with Swift's `UInt64`. I understand that Java's `long` (signed, 2s complement) and Swift's `UInt64` (unsigned) are different, but I imagine it wouldn't be hard to do this with `UInt64`.

I tried `UInt64.byteSwapped`, but this doesn't seem to be getting me the behavior I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Swift standard libraries do not provide a method to reverse the order of *bits* in an integer, see for example the discussion [Bit reversal](https://forums.swift.org/t/bit-reversal/9147) in the Swift forum.

One can use the C methods from [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html), either by importing C code to Swift, or by translating it to Swift.

As an example, I have taken the loop-based variant

```
unsigned int s = sizeof(v) * CHAR_BIT; // bit size; must be power of 2 
unsigned int mask = ~0;         
while ((s >>= 1) > 0) 
{
  mask ^= (mask << s);
  v = ((v >> s) & mask) | ((v << s) & ~mask);
}
```

because that is not restricted to a certain integer size. It can be translated to Swift as an extension to `FixedWidthInteger` so that it works with integers of all sizes:

```
extension FixedWidthInteger {
    var bitSwapped: Self {
        var v = self
        var s = Self(v.bitWidth)
        precondition(s.nonzeroBitCount == 1, "Bit width must be a power of two")
        var mask = ~Self(0)
        repeat  {
            s = s >> 1
            mask ^= mask << s
            v = ((v >> s) & mask) | ((v << s) & ~mask)
        } while s > 1
        return v
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
print(String(UInt64(1).bitSwapped, radix: 16))
// 8000000000000000
print(String(UInt64(0x8070605004030201).bitSwapped, radix: 16))
// 8040c0200a060e01
print(String(UInt16(0x1234).bitSwapped, radix: 16))
// 2c48
```

Another option would be to use `byteSwapped` to reverse the order of bytes first, and then reverse the order of the bits in each byte with a (precomputed) lookup table:

```
fileprivate let bitReverseTable256: [UInt8] = [
    0, 128, 64, 192, 32, 160, 96, 224, 16, 144, 80, 208, 48, 176, 112, 240,
    8, 136, 72, 200, 40, 168, 104, 232, 24, 152, 88, 216, 56, 184, 120, 248,
    4, 132, 68, 196, 36, 164, 100, 228, 20, 148, 84, 212, 52, 180, 116, 244,
    12, 140, 76, 204, 44, 172, 108, 236, 28, 156, 92, 220, 60, 188, 124, 252,
    2, 130, 66, 194, 34, 162, 98, 226, 18, 146, 82, 210, 50, 178, 114, 242,
    10, 138, 74, 202, 42, 170, 106, 234, 26, 154, 90, 218, 58, 186, 122, 250,
    6, 134, 70, 198, 38, 166, 102, 230, 22, 150, 86, 214, 54, 182, 118, 246,
    14, 142, 78, 206, 46, 174, 110, 238, 30, 158, 94, 222, 62, 190, 126, 254,
    1, 129, 65, 193, 33, 161, 97, 225, 17, 145, 81, 209, 49, 177, 113, 241,
    9, 137, 73, 201, 41, 169, 105, 233, 25, 153, 89, 217, 57, 185, 121, 249,
    5, 133, 69, 197, 37, 165, 101, 229, 21, 149, 85, 213, 53, 181, 117, 245,
    13, 141, 77, 205, 45, 173, 109, 237, 29, 157, 93, 221, 61, 189, 125, 253,
    3, 131, 67, 195, 35, 163, 99, 227, 19, 147, 83, 211, 51, 179, 115, 243,
    11, 139, 75, 203, 43, 171, 107, 235, 27, 155, 91, 219, 59, 187, 123, 251,
    7, 135, 71, 199, 39, 167, 103, 231, 23, 151, 87, 215, 55, 183, 119, 247,
    15, 143, 79, 207, 47, 175, 111, 239, 31, 159, 95, 223, 63, 191, 127, 255]

extension FixedWidthInteger {
    var bitSwapped: Self {
        var value = self.byteSwapped
        withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &value) {
            let bytes = $0.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self)
            for i in 0..<bytes.count {
                bytes[i] = bitReverseTable256[Int(bytes[i])]
            }
        }
        return value
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `func CFSwapInt64(UInt64) -> UInt64`, part of Foundation framework? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/byte-order_utilities

Comment: @DavidChopin: `CFSwapInt64` does the same thing as the `byteSwapped` method: It swaps bytes, not bits.

Comment: Yeah reading into that I've picked up on that. I'll go ahead and try some of your suggestions. Thanks!